# Error while setting up the firebase (Using React)

Tags: firebase

I tried to set firebase and whatever written inside firebaseApp is taken from firebase  (databaseURL is not present their in config section)

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

const firebaseApp = firebase.initialzeApp({
        apiKey: "###",
        authDomain: "###",
        projectId: "###",
        storageBucket: "###",
        messagingSenderId: "###",
        appId: "###",
        measurementId: "###"
      
});

const db = firebaseApp.firestore();

export default db ;
```

But i am getting error , which is given below . I tried some solutions but no one worked.

```
Uncaught TypeError: firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default.initialzeApp is not a function

    at Module.<anonymous> (firebase.js:13)

    at Module../src/firebase.js (firebase.js:18)

    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:856)

    at fn (bootstrap:150)

    at Module.<anonymous> (App.css?dde5:82)

    at Module../src/App.js (App.js:62)

    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:856)

    at fn (bootstrap:150)

    at Module.<anonymous> (index.css?bb0a:82)

    at Module../src/index.js (index.js:18)

    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:856)

    at fn (bootstrap:150)

    at Object.1 (reportWebVitals.js:14)

    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:856)

    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)

    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)

    at main.chunk.js:1
```

Please Help
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> const firebaseApp = firebase.initialzeApp

I think it's just a typo, change initialzeApp to initializeApp